# Finding A World Space Vector Using Unproject

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I'm experimenting with LibGDX and 3D in a projection view. Right now I'm looking at how to determine the outermost bounds of my viewport in world space at z=0.0, in order to draw coordinate grid no larger than necessary. However, I seem to have outpaced my education in that I haven't taken a formal linear algebra class and am still a little fuzzy on matrix math.

Is there a way to determine where I should start and stop drawing lines without resorting to using picking and drawing a transparent plane to intersect with?

LibGDX's unproject function takes screen coordinates in a Vector3 and returns a Vector3 in world space from the near clipping plane to the far, given the provided z. However, given that I have a translated and rotated Camera (an encapsulation of the viewprojection matrix and a slew of convenience methods), it occurs to me that I can't pick an arbitrary z to put in the window coordinate vector and just set it to 0.0 after unprojection, as that point probably won't be the furthest viewable point in the viewport. So how do I know what z value to use in the window coordinate that will give the the x and y I need in world space that's at z=0.0?

EDIT (UPDATE):
So apparently it looks like the problem I'm looking at is plane intersection, which would require ray tracing. So now I suppose my question is this: is ray tracing 4 times per render loop (or, I suppose whenever the camera has moved) worth the payoff of being able to dynamically draw a worldspace coordinate grid no larger than the viewport? If not, is there a cheaper algorithm I can use to estimate where I should start and stop drawing lines?

Comment: If i don't misunderstand you http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Culling#View_frustum_culling is what you are looking for right?

Comment: Ray tracing? No... that is something completely different. That implies you trace the path of a ray as it bounces. You can find the world-space extent of your view volume for any window space Z trivially if you have the appropriate matrices and depth range. You either have a frustum (chopped off pyramid) for perspective projection or a constant width/height for all values of Z (orthographic). In the later case, you only need to solve this once.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yeah, ray tracing really describes a specific light-based rendering algorithm, I guess. The reason I mentioned it was that the plane-ray intersect math I was looking for is used in ray tracing. However, I'm not quite sure how to apply the math I've found to my exact problem. I know I can solve my problem with the vector of the window space coords, another point on that vector, and the normal of the plane (which is just {0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, I suppose) using dot products. I'm just not sure how to use the distance value that results from that equation to determine the intersect point.